# Django React -- Deployment Error On Heroku (Page not found 404)

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, webpack, package.json

I'm deploying my Django React project to Heroku. Build was successful, but when I visit the site which is https://django-react-app-nba.herokuapp.com/, I'm getting `django-react-app-nba.herokuapp.com/:14 GET https://django-react-app-nba.herokuapp.com/static/frontend/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

(Development for this project followed this tutorial https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/#Django_REST_with_React_Django_and_React_together)

**ServerError (GET https://django-react-app-nba.herokuapp.com/static/frontend/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found))**

I don't understand why Django is even looking for this URL, could anyone enlighten me?

[image: Server Error]

**My Project Files Path**

[image: My Project Files Path]

**nbavoting urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("frontend.urls")),
    path("", include("teams.urls")),
    path("", include("users.urls")),
]
```

**frontend urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path("", views.index)]
```

**frontend views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

**My guess to the problem is that the router in the frontend is conflicting with server-side routing? (I'm using HashRouter in React)**

Comment: Post your code not image please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to run "npm run build" :D

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to run "npm run build"...